# Spark not distributing load to tasks evenly

Tags: apache-spark

RDD.saveAsTextFile the last stage is very slow. I am suspecting that the issues that the records are not evenly distributed across partitions and tasks. Is there any way to force this?

[image: Last Task never finishes]

```
   public static JavaRDD<String> getJsonUserIdVideoIdRDD(JavaRDD<Rating> cachedRating,
                                                      JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> userIdClusterId,
                                                      int numPartitions, String outDir){
    /*
     convert the JavaRDD<Rating>  to JavaPairRDD<Integer,DmRating>
     */
    JavaPairRDD<Integer,DmRating> userIdDmRating = cachedRating.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Rating, Integer, DmRating>() {
        public Tuple2<Integer, DmRating> call(Rating dmRating) throws Exception {
            return new Tuple2<>(dmRating.user(), (DmRating)dmRating);
        }
    });

    /*
    join this RDD with userIdClusterID RDD by key
     */
    JavaPairRDD<Integer, Tuple2<Integer, DmRating>> userId_T_clusterIdDmRating = userIdClusterId.join(userIdDmRating, numPartitions);

    // extract the clusterId to videoId map
    JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> clusterIdVideoId =  userId_T_clusterIdDmRating.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<Integer, Tuple2<Integer,DmRating>>, Integer, Integer>() {
        public Tuple2<Integer, Integer> call(Tuple2<Integer, Tuple2<Integer, DmRating>> userIdDmRatingClusterId ) throws Exception {
            Integer userId = userIdDmRatingClusterId._1();
            Tuple2<Integer, DmRating> dmRatingClusterId = userIdDmRatingClusterId._2();
            return new Tuple2<Integer, Integer>(dmRatingClusterId._1(), dmRatingClusterId._2().product());
        }
    });
    //////
    /// Count the popularity of a video in a cluster
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> clusterIdVideoIdStrInt = clusterIdVideoId.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>, String, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(Tuple2<Integer, Integer> videoIdClusterId) throws Exception {
            return new Tuple2<>(String.format("%d:%d", videoIdClusterId._1(), videoIdClusterId._2()), 1);
        }
    });
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> clusterIdVideoIdStrCount =   clusterIdVideoIdStrInt.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call(Integer v1, Integer v2) throws Exception {
            return v1+v2;
        }
    });
    ///

    JavaPairRDD<Integer, Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> clusterId_T_videoIdCount = clusterIdVideoIdStrCount.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Integer, Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<Integer, Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> call(Tuple2<String, Integer> clusterIdVideoIdStrCount) throws Exception {
            String[] splits = clusterIdVideoIdStrCount._1().split(":");
            try{
                if(splits.length==2){
                    int clusterId = Integer.parseInt(splits[0]);
                    int videoId = Integer.parseInt(splits[1]);
                    return new Tuple2<>(clusterId, new Tuple2<>(videoId, clusterIdVideoIdStrCount._2()));
                }else{
                    //Should never occur
                    LOGGER.error("Could not split {} into two with : as the separator!", clusterIdVideoIdStrCount._1());
                }
            }catch (NumberFormatException ex){
                LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage());
            }
            return new Tuple2<>(-1, new Tuple2<>(-1,-1));
        }
    });

    JavaPairRDD<Integer, Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>> clusterIdVideoIdGrouped = clusterId_T_videoIdCount.groupByKey();

    JavaPairRDD<Integer, DmRating> clusterIdDmRating = userId_T_clusterIdDmRating.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<Integer, Tuple2<Integer, DmRating>>, Integer, DmRating>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<Integer, DmRating> call(Tuple2<Integer, Tuple2<Integer, DmRating>> userId_T_clusterIdDmRating) throws Exception {
           return userId_T_clusterIdDmRating._2();
        }
    });

    JavaPairRDD<Integer, Tuple2<DmRating, Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>>> clusterId_T_DmRatingVideoIds = clusterIdDmRating.join(clusterIdVideoIdGrouped, numPartitions);

    JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> userIdStringRDD = clusterId_T_DmRatingVideoIds.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<Integer, Tuple2<DmRating, Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>>>, Integer, String>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<Integer, String> call(Tuple2<Integer, Tuple2<DmRating, Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>>> v1) throws Exception {
            int clusterId = v1._1();
            Tuple2<DmRating, Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>> tuple = v1._2();
            DmRating rating = tuple._1();
            Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> videosCounts= tuple._2();
            StringBuilder recosStr = new StringBuilder();
            boolean appendComa = false;
            for(Tuple2<Integer, Integer> videoCount : videosCounts){
                if(appendComa) recosStr.append(",");
                recosStr.append("{");
                recosStr.append("\"video_id\":");
                recosStr.append(videoCount._1());
                recosStr.append(",");
                recosStr.append("\"count\":");
                recosStr.append(videoCount._2());
                recosStr.append("}");
                appendComa = true;
            }
            String val = String.format("{\"user_id\":\"%s\",\"v1st\":\"%s\",\"redis_uid\":%s,\"cluster_id\": %d,\"recommendations\":[  %s ]}", rating.dmUserId,  rating.dmV1stStr, rating.user(), clusterId, recosStr);
            return new Tuple2<Integer, String>(rating.user(), val);
        }
    });
    JavaPairRDD<Integer, Iterable<String>> groupedRdd = userIdStringRDD.groupByKey(numPartitions);
    JavaRDD<String> jsonStringRdd = groupedRdd.map(new Function<Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<String>>, String>() {
        @Override
        public String call(Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<String>> v1) throws Exception {
            for(String str : v1._2()){
                return str;
            }
            LOGGER.error("Could not fetch a string from iterable so returning empty");
            return "";
        }
    });

    //LOGGER.info("Number of items in RDD: {}", jsonStringRDD.count());
    //return jsonStringRDD.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2());
    LOGGER.info("Repartitioning the data into {}", numPartitions );
    jsonStringRdd.cache().saveAsTextFile(outDir);
    return jsonStringRdd;
}
```

Cluster Size:
1. Master : 16 CPU, 32GB
2. Workers 4 : 32CPU, 102GB, 4X375GB SSD Drives

I changed the code to use DataFrames instead. Still the same issue

```
public static void saveAlsKMeansRecosAsParquet(JavaPairRDD<Integer, Tuple2<DmRating, Integer>> userIdRatingClusterIdRDD,
                                                 int numPartitions,
                                                 JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext,
                                                 String outdir){

    JavaRDD<DmRating> dmRatingJavaRDD = userIdRatingClusterIdRDD.map(new Function<Tuple2<Integer, Tuple2<DmRating, Integer>>, DmRating>() {
        public DmRating call(Tuple2<Integer, Tuple2<DmRating, Integer>> v1) throws Exception {
            //Integer userId = v1._1();
            Tuple2<DmRating, Integer> values = v1._2();
            DmRating rating = values._1();
            Integer clusterId = values._2();
            rating.setClusterId(clusterId);
            rating.setVideoId(rating.product());
            rating.setV1stOrUserId((rating.userId== null || rating.userId.isEmpty())? rating.v1stId : rating.userId);
            rating.setRedisId(rating.user());
            return rating;
            //return String.format("{\"clusterId\": %s,\"userId\": %s, \"userId\":\"%s\", \"videoId\": %s}", clusterId, userId, rating.userId, rating.product());
        }
    });
    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(javaSparkContext);
    DataFrame dmRatingDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dmRatingJavaRDD, DmRating.class);
    dmRatingDF.registerTempTable("dmrating");
    DataFrame clusterIdVideoIdDF = sqlContext.sql("SELECT clusterId, videoId FROM dmrating").cache();
    DataFrame rolledupClusterIdVideoIdDF = clusterIdVideoIdDF.rollup("clusterId","videoId").count().cache();
    DataFrame clusterIdUserIdDF = sqlContext.sql("SELECT clusterId, userId, redisId, v1stId FROM dmrating").distinct().cache();
    JavaRDD<Row> rolledUpRDD = rolledupClusterIdVideoIdDF.toJavaRDD();
    JavaRDD<Row> filteredRolledUpRDD = rolledUpRDD.filter(new Function<Row, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(Row v1) throws Exception {
            //make sure the size and values of the properties are correct
            return !(v1.size()!=3 || v1.isNullAt(0) || v1.isNullAt(1) || v1.isNullAt(2));
        }
    });

    JavaPairRDD<Integer, Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> clusterIdVideoIdCount = filteredRolledUpRDD.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Row, Integer, Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<Integer, Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> call(Row row) throws Exception {
            Tuple2<Integer, Integer> videoIdCount = new Tuple2<Integer, Integer>(row.getInt(1), Long.valueOf(row.getLong(2)).intValue());
            return new Tuple2<Integer, Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>(row.getInt(0),videoIdCount);
        }
    }).cache();
    JavaPairRDD<Integer, Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>> groupedPair = clusterIdVideoIdCount.groupByKey(numPartitions).cache();
    JavaRDD<ClusterIdVideos> groupedFlat = groupedPair.map(new Function<Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>>, ClusterIdVideos>() {
        @Override
        public ClusterIdVideos call(Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>> v1) throws Exception {
            ClusterIdVideos row = new ClusterIdVideos();
            Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> videosCounts= v1._2();
            StringBuilder recosStr = new StringBuilder();
            recosStr.append("[");
            boolean appendComa = false;
            for(Tuple2<Integer, Integer> videoCount : videosCounts){
                if(appendComa) recosStr.append(",");
                recosStr.append("{");
                recosStr.append("\"video_id\":");
                recosStr.append(videoCount._1());
                recosStr.append(",");
                recosStr.append("\"count\":");
                recosStr.append(videoCount._2());
                recosStr.append("}");
                appendComa = true;
            }
            recosStr.append("]");
            row.setClusterId(v1._1());
            row.setVideos(recosStr.toString());
            return row;
        }
    }).cache();

    DataFrame groupedClusterId = sqlContext.createDataFrame(groupedFlat, ClusterIdVideos.class);
    DataFrame recosDf = clusterIdUserIdDF.join(groupedClusterId, "clusterId");
    recosDf.write().parquet(outdir);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use "<RDD>.repartition(numPartitions: Int)". It will increase the parallelism but that may not solve your problem...can you post the code.

Comment: tried that .. does not effect the time or the partititions

Comment: We may be able to help but need to see the code. So please post the code.

Comment: It may not be "saveAsTextFile()" which is causing the delay. "saveAs.." is an Action which is triggering all other computations defined in the job. I would suggest to look into each of the stages and see which operation is taking most of the time. Also please provide some sample data, size of your cluster and total size of data, I will try out and will try to optimize the performance. You can also enable the History server for analyzing the completed jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found the issue. The culprits were groupBy and join operations. The documentation on the Spark's Website says

> In Spark, data is generally not distributed across partitions to be in the necessary place for a specific operation. During computations, a single task will operate on a single partition - thus, to organize all the data for a single reduceByKey reduce task to execute, Spark needs to perform an all-to-all operation. It must read from all partitions to find all the values for all keys, and then bring together values across partitions to compute the final result for each key - this is called the shuffle.

To optimize any join/groupByKey operations, the goal should be to reduce the shuffle. I found [this deck](http://www.slideshare.net/databricks/strata-sj-everyday-im-shuffling-tips-for-writing-better-spark-programs/) very helpful in diagnosing the problem. Especially the slide [12](http://www.slideshare.net/databricks/strata-sj-everyday-im-shuffling-tips-for-writing-better-spark-programs/12).

I know that the cluster ids data is very small, 100 clusters per run, so I created a broadcast variable for the smaller table and broadcast it to all executors and use that variable for join. This worked well and reduced the computation time from 2hrs to 10mins.

```
    //convert json string to DF
    DataFrame  groupedClusterId = sqlContext.read().json(groupedFlat.rdd());
    Broadcast<DataFrame> broadcastDataFrame= javaSparkContext.broadcast(groupedClusterId);

    DataFrame recosDf = clusterIdUserIdDF.join(broadcastDataFrame.value(),"clusterId");
    recosDf.write().parquet(outdir);
```