# Spark : Job stuck on the last 2 tasks of 100

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata

I am new to Spark and I must support an application that has been written by our consultant.  I read and watched a tons of information about Spark but still I'm struggling with the little details to tune the job correctly.

The scenario:

1. Java class that contains 5 cleansing rules that we apply on a RDD of 400 millions records.
2. Number of partition is set to 1000.
3. The final "action" is a write on S3 but prior to that we reduce the number of partitions to 100.
4. Spark UI shows the progression but unfortunately on the last stage of the save, the tasks are stuck at 98/100
5. I'm not using .collect() but I'm using .map() and Spark SQL.

Here is the code I'm using to write:

```java
rdd.coalesce(100)
   .write().mode("append")
   .partitionBy("year", "month")
   .format(SPARK_AVRO_PACKAGE)
   .save(appProps.getProperty(PAGEVIEW_CLEANSED));
```

I am not sure if I should put effort on improving the code or tuning the performance of the spark / cluster.

*UPDATE*: I think this snippet of code is responsible for the problem I'm experiencing.  I found a similar post on SO ([Spark not distributing load to tasks evenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048340/spark-not-distributing-load-to-tasks-evenly)), I'm just not sure how to use broadcast in my situation.

```java
Dataset<Row> duplicatePrefetchPrerenderHashDS = 
            hashedPageViewDS
              .select(hashedPageViewDS.col(PREFETCH_PRERENDER_HASH))
              .groupBy(hashedPageViewDS.col(PREFETCH_PRERENDER_HASH))
              .count()
              .withColumnRenamed("count", "cnt")
              .where("cnt>1");
```

Comment: Short - data skew. But we won't know where exactly, unless you show upstream code.

Comment: How can I share so much code with you?

Comment: This is the point of creating a [mcve]. But to make it simpler look for the first `join` / `groupByKey` / `groupBy` + `agg` + non-reducing function (like `collect_list`) / `Window` function application upstream of the writer code. And of course `coalesce` can cause its own problems. One way or another - problem is not here or not here alone.

Comment: Thanks for the support.  I can confirm that we use coalesce to reduce the number of partitions created when we start the Spark job (1000) before writing to S3 and join / groupBy (Spark SQL).  Do you think a custom Partitioner would help redistributing the records equally amongst all the partitions?

Comment: There are no custom partitioners in SQL. But I wouldn't expect a huge improvement even if there where, if problem is indeed data skew, not some regularities.

Comment: you can try to check result partition sizes for debug:
rdd.foreachPartition(x=> println(x.size))
if this code stuck, you have no s3 issues.
if the sizes are really unequals. use repartition(100) instead of coalesce(100), it will give you equals partitions

Comment: I'm testing that right now! Thanks @ArtemAliev

Comment: @GeoffL. Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I end up rewriting everything using Scala instead of Java and we found a data skew issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches you can take:

1. Can you try and do distributeBy("year", "month") this will ensure that there is only 1 partition writing to each folder. If the data is evenly distributed among the years and months.
2. If the problem is in fact the skewed on certain years. Then I would say to use repartition(1000) along with use distributeBy("year", "month","COL1"). In the above example COL1 will be a column that is nearly evently distributed like DAY of MONTH or DATE. Now rather than writing 200 (default shuffle sort value) files to each partition, the COL1 will decide the no files being written (30 is there is DAY OF MONTH)
3. Another Thing that will help is to use repartition(100) instead of coalesce(100) because repartition will evenly distribute the data causing more partitions to have the data for each partition in your output.

Comment: I've changed _coalesce_ to _repartition_ but I have the same behavior.  I'm curious to see how I can use _distributeBy_ in Java, it's worth a try!  Thank you!

Comment: Distribute by equivalent in DataFrame API is `df.repartition($"key", 2)`